# Why is my forward to std::make_pair in a separate namespace ambiguous?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++14

Disclaimer: This is more or less for educational purposes, so a discussion about the meaningfulness of the shown wrapping should be neglected.

Consider the following template in its own namespace:

```
// file my_make_pair.h

#pragma once
#include <utility>

namespace fc {

    template<typename T, typename U>
    decltype(auto) make_pair(T&& first, U&& second)
    {
        return std::make_pair(std::forward<T>(first),
                              std::forward<U>(second));
    }

}
```

When I try to use it from within this namespace:

```
// file my_test.cpp

#include "my_make_pair.h"
#include <string>

namespace fc {

    void my_function(const std::string& name) {
        auto my_pair = make_pair(name, 42);
    }

}
```

I get the following compiler error:

```
could be 'decltype(auto) fc::make_pair<const std::string&,int>(T,U &&)'
    with
    [
        T=const std::string &,
        U=int
    ]

or 'std::pair<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >,int> std::make_pair<const std::string&,int>(_Ty1,_Ty2 &&)'
                     [found using argument-dependent lookup]
    with
    [
        _Ty1=const std::string &,
        _Ty2=int
    ]
```

As soon as I rename my wrapper to something else, e.g. `make_my_pair`, everything works.

It also seems to be related to the const reference parameter of `fc::my_function` which I use for the first value of the pair. When I change the call to my wrapper to just use (primitive) rvalues, e.g. `auto my_pair = fc::make_pair(1.42, 42);`, everything works. It also works, when I directly use `std::make_pair`.

Why does the compiler take the implementation of the std namespace into account in the first place? I did not explicitly use `std::make_pair` (with the exception of the wrapper definition) nor did I do `using namespace std` at any time. I am using Visual Studio 2015 (VC14).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call is ambiguous because of [Argument Dependent-name Lookup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup) (ADL). Because your argument is a `std::string`, then the `make_pair()` in namespace `std` is considered.

This is why, for example when you call `std::cout << 21`, you do not need to specify the namespace `std` for `operator<<`: because of ADL it is figured by the compiler.

If you want to enforce that your own implementation is used, then you need to prefix the call with the namespace `fc::make_pair(...)`.

Comment: Thank you, such a simple explanation I haven't thought about. Even in the presence of `[found using argument-dependent lookup]` (I did see this but thought about template deduction).

Comment: @Daniel You're welcome! Don't forget to accept my answer if it solved your problem.